# Update from TF 1.2 to TF 2.X Bıdırectıonal throws object is not iterable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to update the below code from TF 1.2 to TF 2.0. When I run the code with all the "old" lines (inditaced by the comment `old` above them"), I get the following warnings:

```
WARNING: LSTMCell.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This class is equivalent as tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell, and will be replaced by that in Tensorflow 2.0.

WARNING: MultiRNNCell.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This class is equivalent as tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells, and will be replaced by that in Tensorflow 2.0.

WARNING: bidirectional_dynamic_rnn (from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.RNN(cell))`, which is equivalent to this API
```

So I have done updates as instructed in the warnings (These are the lines with `new` as comment above them.). However, I am getting the following error:

```
in setupRNN ((fw, bw), _) = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.RNN(stacked))
TypeError: 'Bidirectional' object is not iterable
```

What is the cause of this error and any tips on how to implement the 'tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional' better in code?

Thank you for your effort and help in advance.

```
def setupRNN(self):
        rnnIn3d = tf.squeeze(self.cnnOut4d, axis=[2])
        numHidden = 256

        # old: 
        # cells = [tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=numHidden, state_is_tuple=True) for _ in range(2)] # 2 layers

        # new:
        cells = [tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(units=numHidden) for _ in range(2)]


        # old:
        # stacked = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells, state_is_tuple=True)

        # new:       
        stacked = tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells(cells)


        # old:
        # ((fw, bw), _) = tf.compat.v1.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=stacked, cell_bw=stacked, inputs=rnnIn3d, dtype=rnnIn3d.dtype)

        # new:  
        ((fw, bw), _) = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.RNN(stacked))

        concat = tf.expand_dims(tf.concat([fw, bw], 2), 2)

        kernel = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([1, 1, numHidden * 2, len(self.charList) + 1], stddev=0.1))
        self.rnnOut3d = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(value=concat, filters=kernel, rate=1, padding='SAME'), axis=[2])
```

Comment: try replacing `stacked = tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells(cells)` with `stacked = tf.keras.layers.RNN(cells)`

Comment: Hello, just tried this, and unfortunately making the above replacement causes the following error: `ValueError: The RNN cell should have an attribute state_size (tuple of integers, one integer per RNN state).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional` you need to provide one of these layers as input.
`keras.layers.RNN` , `keras.layers.LSTM` , `keras.layers.GRU` or  `keras.layers.Layer`.

In your case, you are using `keras.layers.RNN` with stacked `LSTMCell`, which fails the criteria for tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional even if you use single LSTMCell, because it does not have  attribute `go_backwards` in it.

Let me explain to you with few examples.

**Example 1:**

```
cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=20) 

tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(cell)
```

result:

```
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.wrappers.Bidirectional at 0x7f89a9fa05c0>
```

Here if you provide a single LSTM layer as input to `Bidirectional`, the layer instance passed as the layer argument will be used to generate the backward layer automatically.

**Example 2:**

You can mention 2 separate layers that satisfy the Bidirectional conditions.

```
forward_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=20)
backward_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=20,go_backwards=True)
```

Note that, you need to mention go_backwards=True for one of the layers and use that as a backward layer in Bidirectional.

```
tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(forward_layer, backward_layer=backward_layer)
```

result:

```
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.wrappers.Bidirectional at 0x7f89a9f2fb00>
```

You can also refer to the documentation from TensorFlow and make changes or rewrite the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason I thought stacked LSTM cells would still work for tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional and that was the general problem.